# Bluetooth Device Name Change No Updates

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using a BLU Advanced 5.0 device running on lollipop and I am currently using it as my developer phone, I am writing a program that uses BLE to read the name of a device that has data about the device. I do not connect to this device all I do is read the name of it. Here is my problem, so the Bluetooth device name when I scan never changes even though it does, for example

```
7ebb6486aa21db2197
```

That is the name I would get back from the BLE scan, but when I change the values on the BLE Device the name would change, for example

```
7ebb6486aa21db2199
```

But when I scan the name wouldn't update it will still show the old name and I cant figure out how to get the name to update. Its bad because the device is not connectable so I can figure out a way to subscribe with GATT to the name. The only way I can get the values to change is when I restart the Bluetooth on the phone and that is the only way I could find.

Comment: Pretty sure you can just simply re-scan with `startDiscovery`.

Comment: That does not seem to work, The only way it will change is when I restart the Bluetooth. @MuratK.

Comment: [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10171843/how-to-prevent-name-caching-and-detect-bluetooth-name-changes-on-discovery). Did not test it tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only scan and never connect, just parse the scanRecord and get the name from there.